# Calculate mean from subset of rows in pandas data frame: groupby or for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a data frame that gives the number of `Fruit` in two bowls `A` and `B`, that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit':['apple','apple','pear','pear','banana','banana'],
'Bowl': ['A','B','A','B','A','B'],
'Value':[15, 20, 332, 240, 344, 211]}); df

    Fruit   Bowl    Value
    apple   A       15
    apple   B       20
    pear    A       332
    pear    B       240
    banana  A       311
    banana  B       211
```

And I have the total number of fruits in bowls "A" and "B".

```
num = pd.DataFrame({'Bowl': ['A','B'], 'Num': [330, 200]}); num

    Num   Type
    330   A
    200   B
```

What's an elegant way to get the percentage (proportion * 100, `Prop`) of fruit within of each type in each bowl, using `num`?

```
    Fruit   Bowl    Value  Prop
    apple   A       15     4.55  
    apple   B       20     ...
    pear    A       332    
    pear    B       240    
    banana  A       45    
    banana  B       27
```

So the calculation in `Prop` is for example (number of apples in bowl A (15) divided by total number of fruit in bowl A (330) *100 = 4.55.)

**Note that the total number of fruit is not the sum of apple + pear + banana in bowl "A". You have to use the numbers given in `num` because there are actually more types of fruit in the bowl.

Comment: Doesn't `df.Value / df.groupby('Bowl').Value.transform('sum') * 100` do what you want?

Comment: @coldspeed I realized a mistake in the question. I can't just sum the values of the fruits in each bowl, A and B, but rather use the values in Num.num.

Comment: I have fixed your question because this was not clear initially. I've also added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by first 'merging' the `num` column to your main df and than calculating the proportions like this:

```
# first merge
df_final = pd.merge(df, num, on='Bowl')

# calculate the proportion
df_final['Prop'] = round(df_final.Value / df_final.Num * 100, 2) 

# drop the column Num which was not asked in the output
df_final.drop('Num', axis=1, inplace=True)

    Fruit   Bowl    Value   Prop
0   apple   A       15      3.53
1   pear    A       332     78.12
2   banana  A       344     80.94
3   apple   B       20      6.35
4   pear    B       240     76.19
5   banana  B       211     66.98
```

Comment: This was a nice, well-commented solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
df.set_index('Bowl').Value.div(num.set_index('Bowl').Num)*100
Out[72]: 
Bowl
A      4.545455
A    100.606061
A    104.242424
B     10.000000
B    120.000000
B    105.500000
dtype: float64
#df['Prop']=df.set_index('Bowl').Value.div(num.set_index('Bowl').Num)*100.values
```